# How to redirect output back to the display for a single command

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

In a shell script i have

```
LOG=/my.log
exec 1>>$LOG
exec 2>&1
```

which redirects the output in shell script. Now the problem is in the following

```
LOG=/etc/security/aixpert/log/aixpert.log
exec 1>>$LOG
exec 2>&1

#some codes

print "I want this on cmd output not in log"

#I want rest of the output redirected to log as usual
```

How can i do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to clone `stdout` going to the console to an arbitrary fd (I chose 3) before your redirect it to your log.  Whenever you want to send output to the console you just redirect fd 1 back to fd 3 with `>&3` for that one command

```
LOG=/etc/security/aixpert/log/aixpert.log

exec 3>&1 >>"$LOG" 2>&1

#some codes

echo "I want this on cmd output not in log" >&3

#I want rest of the output redirected to log as usual
```

Comment: Is it fine to pick any fd? Isn't there a possibility that 3 is fd assigned to a file opened by another application which it is operating on?

Answer (score 2):

```
# save stdout as fd 3
exec 3>&1
exec 1>>$LOG
exec 2>&1

echo foo >&3  # output to old stdout
echo bar      # output to logfile
```

Comment: @SiegeX: thanks :) +1 to your answer too, I think you were actually a few seconds earlier.